# How can I implement upload button in J frame in user registration page?

Tags: java, swing, jakarta-ee, jframe

I have written two methods:
Both are working fine. But I'm getting confuse how to use them for submit button action.
Button browse will get and read the image only where button submit (create account) will verify all the fields and then store the image into a specific folder.
textField_3 is the text-box before upload button(show the image path) and textField_1 is the text-box for username(username.jpg would be the final image name).
All the fields will store in the database only image will store into a specific folder.

[image]

```
        void browse()   //Browse the image from local folder 
        {

            JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();

            chooser.showOpenDialog(null);
            File f = chooser.getSelectedFile();
            filename = f.getAbsolutePath();
            textField_3.setText(filename);  


        }


        void browse_store()  //store the image in source folder
        {


            JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
            int returnVal = chooser.showOpenDialog(null); 
            File f = chooser.getSelectedFile();
            filename = f.getAbsolutePath();
            //File file = chooser.getSelectedFile(textField_3.getText());

            FileNameExtensionFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter(
                    "JPG, GIF, and PNG Images", "jpg", "gif", "png");
            chooser.setFileFilter(filter);


            String withExtension = chooser.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath();

            if( !withExtension.toLowerCase().endsWith( ".jpg" ))  //check validation of .jpg file
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Choose jpg image");
            }


            else if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {

                    System.out.println("You choose to open this file: "+ f.getName());


                    BufferedImage image;      

                     try {

                        image = ImageIO.read(f);
                        ImageIO.write(image, "jpg",new File("D:\\Img\\" + textField_1.getText()+".jpg"));
                    } catch (IOException ex) {
                        Logger.getLogger(Register.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                    }              
                }



        }



        String filename = null; //global declaration for string variable filename 


}
```

---

Whenever I am calling the method browse_store then dialog is opening again(since I've written:

```
JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
int returnVal = chooser.showOpenDialog(null);
```

)

Comment: Don't call it "upload" but call it "browse" or something else instead

Comment: Do you have any suggestion how to solve this ?

Comment: Don't bold text for no reason.